# how can round the number in specific format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

I want to round the number in specific format in jquery

For ex.

```
var First = 3.52
```

if last value after decimal point `2` is less then 3 then it should be round to 0

if last value after decimal point `2` is beetween then 3 to 7 then it should be round to 5

if last value after decimal point `2` is more then 7 then it should be round to 10

Like

```
if(var First = 1.21) { var Answer = 1.20 }
if(var First = 1.24) { var Answer = 1.25 }
if(var First = 1.28) { var Answer = 1.30 }
```

i have tried Round and Ceil , Floor but doesnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use `Math.round()` to the nearest 0.05, like this:

```
Math.round(number * 20) / 20;
```

To make it easier you can extract this to a function:

```js
console.log(round(1.21)); // = 1.20
console.log(round(1.24)); // = 1.25
console.log(round(1.28)); // = 1.30

function round(num) {
  return (Math.round(num * 20) / 20).toFixed(2);
}
```

Note the use of `toFixed(2)` to force the result to 2 decimal places. Beware that this method returns a string, so if you are planning on doing any calculations with the value you will need to run the result through `parseFloat()`.

Comment: And combine it with toFixed: `[1.21, 1.24, 1.28, 3.52].map(v => (((v*20)|0)/20).toFixed(2))`

Comment: @DenysSéguret Thanks, missed the forcing to 2dp.